Is there a way to abort asynchronous sleep at a random moment
I need my program to stop asynchronous sleep on change of a variable. Googling only yields as a possible solution wrapping asyncio.sleep in a task to be cancelled, like this:

import asyncio

async def f(duration: int) -> None:
    await asyncio.sleep(duration)

async def main():
    condition = False
    task = asyncio.create_task(f(10))
    await task
    condition = bool(some_random_bool)
    """^^^this is supposed to be set
    somewhere within the ten seconds;
    in my case it should be a change
    of a telegram user's state"""
    if condition:
        task.cancel()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())

But this code doesn't work the way I want it to, because a task already awaited won't cancel. It only will if you put the cancel line before the await-task one. I don't quite understand what's the point of awaiting a task after cancelling it beforehand (maybe I'm off in my understanding of async lingo and cancel() is not what I need).
So I'm wondering if there actually is a way of stopping halfway through a task around a coroutine.

Reading about task cancel will help you understand the logic (There's a nice example). https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task.cancel

If you want to interrupt sleeping on new events, then don't sleep. Instead await the new events with a timeout. done, pending = await asyncio.wait((event1, event2, ), timeout=duration, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED) If done is empty, you know you had a timeout

The common way to use asyncio.sleep is in race scenarios. If you want to wait until some value get change, you can define an asyncio.Future and create another task to set the result of it.
I have implemented a basic usage of what you can possibly do:
import asyncio
import sys


async def task_fn(future: asyncio.Future):
    try:
        ## Main logic
        # I've implemented a read from input in async way
        reader = asyncio.StreamReader()
        protocol = asyncio.StreamReaderProtocol(reader)

        # Get the running loop
        loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
        await loop.connect_read_pipe(lambda: protocol, sys.stdin)
        print("Reading...")
        res = b""
        while not reader.at_eof() and b"\n" not in res:
            res += await reader.read(1)

        # Set the future result at the end
        future.set_result(str(res.decode().strip()))
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        # task_fn was cancelled
        pass


async def race_fn(timeout_seconds: int):
    future = asyncio.Future()

    # Schedule the main task
    task = asyncio.create_task(task_fn(future))

    # Schedule the timer task
    timer_task = asyncio.create_task(asyncio.sleep(timeout_seconds), name="timer")

    # Wait until either task completes
    done, pending = await asyncio.wait(
        [timer_task, task], return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED
    )

    # Cancel the pending task
    pending.pop().cancel()

    # Check which task completed
    done_task = done.pop()
    if done_task.get_name() == "timer":
        print("[FAILED] Timeout occurred before user input.")
    else:
        print(f"[OK] Input received: {future.result()}")


asyncio.run(race_fn(2))

In this example it tries to read input from the user until it reaches '\n' and have 2 seconds timeout which races with the main task.

That seems to be something I can draw upon, thanks a lot!

So glad you find it useful.
